# Underline Text in a barplot in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to underline the mean value in the following plot:

```
dummy <- c(4, 9, 6, 5, 3)
barplot(dummy)
text(4, 8,paste('Average value', mean(dummy)))
```

I tried using `underline()` but it says it could not find the function.

```
text(4, 8,paste('Average value', underline(mean(dummy))))
```

**Error:**

```
could not find function "underline"
```

I am using : R version 3.1.0

Comment: can u pls put ur error here...

Comment: Not sure if there's a function but there is a workaround - https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-January/018012.html - to draw the line in 'manually'.

Comment: Do you want "average value" underlined as well or just "5.4"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like this:

```
text(4, 8, bquote("Average value"~underline(.(mean(dummy)))))
```

or if you want the whole text underlined:

```
text(4, 8, bquote(underline("Average value"~.(mean(dummy)))))
```

Note use of `bquote` and `.(x)` to insert the value of a variable in the expression.

Answer (score 3):

I could not access the link provided by @EddieSanders but I think this link is probably to the same solution: http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/02a/0471.html

```
underlined <- function(x, y, label, ...){ 
    text(x, y, label, ...) 
    sw <- strwidth(label) 
    sh <- strheight(label) 
    lines(x + c(-sw/2, sw/2), rep(y - 1.5*sh/2, 2)) 
  } 

dummy <- c(4, 9, 6, 5, 3)
barplot(dummy)
text(4, 8, underlined(4,8,paste('Average value', mean(dummy))), font=2)
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

This will underline just the mean value:

```
underlined <- function(x, y, label, ...){ 
    text(x, y, label, ...) 
    sw <- strwidth(label) 
    sh <- strheight(label) 
    lines(x + c(-sw/2, sw/2), rep(y - 1.5*sh/2, 2)) 
  } 

dummy <- c(4, 9, 6, 5, 3)

barplot(dummy)

text(4, 8, paste('Average value', underlined(4.9,8,mean(dummy))))
```

Comment: I need to underline just the numeric mean value

Comment: Thank you. As @spacedman has pointed out, there is much more simpler way to do it.

Comment: @Omley Feel free to compare the result from both approaches and decide which you prefer.  I prefer the spacing between the numbers and the line from the code I posted.  If that spacing can be adjusted with Spacedman's code I would prefer his approach.