# How to underline Text in an R Plot?

Tags: r, text, underline, word-cloud

I am playing with the source code of comparison.cloud from Ian Fellows. 
I want to highlight some of the text by underlining it based on some criteria:

```
text(x1,y1,words[i],cex=size[i],offset=0,srt=rotWord*90, font=3,
         col=colors[group[i]],...)
```

I am unable to find a way, I checked the `par()` of text, could not find a solution, used the `underline()`, did not work either, `bquote(underline(..))` did not work either. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988052/underline-text-in-a-barplot-in-r